# Getting Translation of view with UIPanGestureRecognizer - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uitextfield, translation, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm translating a view using a UIPanGestureRecognizer method:

```
 @objc fileprivate func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        makeDisappearButtons()
        deletebox.isHidden = false
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        if gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.intersects(deletebox.frame) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
                self.deletebox.transform = .init(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            gestureRecognizer.view!.setNeedsDisplay()
            gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.deletebox.transform = .identity
                gestureRecognizer.view!.transform = .identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        makeButtonsReAppear()
        if gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.intersects(deletebox.frame) {
            gestureRecognizer.view!.isHidden = true
            gestureRecognizer.view?.removeFromSuperview()
        } else {
            gestureRecognizer.view!.setNeedsDisplay()
            gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
            gestureRecognizer.view!.transform = .identity
        }
        print(gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view))
        deletebox.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

I want to know the translation of the view in gestureRecognizer.state == .ended but when I try to print it out it is x:0, y:0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the translation back to `.zero` every time the gesture handler calls `changed`.

```
gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
```

However, the state changes to `ended` when the finger lifts up, and by that time the translation doesn't change anymore.
The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_pan_gestures) says:

> When the user’s fingers lift from the screen, the gesture recognizer enters the UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended state.

So the translation is the **same** on the last `changed` call *and* the `ended` -- and because you're already setting the frame of `gestureRecognizer.view` inside `changed`, you don't need to do anything inside `ended`.

Answer (score 0):

From where have you called this method, may be put it in viewDidAppear and try. Otherwise call setNeedsDisplay and LayoutIfNeeded methods.

Comment: This method is called by the gesture recognizer, not manually. I don't think `setNeedsDisplay` or `layoutIfNeeded` would have any effect either.

Comment: The method is called by the gesture recogniser